# Selenium RC link locator cannot find link inside table

Tags: testing, selenium

I has a page as follow:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="www.whatever.com"> What Ever Company</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The company name is placed arbitrary in the table, so I can only use the link's text to locate the link:

```
selenium.click("link='What Ever Company'");
```

However, it says: `ERROR:Element link='What Ever Company' not found.`

What is the problem here? Is there any other way to click on the link?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**
Seem that the problem is I have several links with the same text (my bad). After making the link's text unique, I use `selenium.click("//a[contains(text(),'Test Campaign 1756237989')]")` and it works.

Comment: If you control the site content, you can set ids to your DOM elements to uniquely identify them more easily when testing. Looks better than adding funky numbers to your links.

Comment: Thanks, the funky numbers is because customer don't want to delete anything ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be because you're forgetting the space at the start of the link?

```
selenium.click("link=' What Ever Company'");
                      ^
```

Another possible way of clicking the link, is to use an XPath expression:

```
selenium.click("//a[contains(.,'What Ever Company')]");
```

This will match all links with 'What Ever Company' in it.

If you want it more exact:

```
selenium.click("//a[.=' What Ever Company']");
```

This will only match if the anchor equals ' What Ever Company'.

Another option is to make the search more specific (i.e. tell the locator this link is always inside a `<td>` with an `<a>` inside):

```
selenium.click("//td[a]/a[contains(.,'What Ever Company')]");
```

The `//td[a]` looks for all `<td>` elements with `<a>` inside. (Differs from `//td/a` in that if you look for elements with `//td[a][2]` you get the second `<a>` which is inside a `<td>`, while `//td/a[2]` on the other hand gets the second `<a>` of the first `<td>`.)

EDIT: I thought using `.` as a reference to `text()` in the XPath expressions should work, but if it doesn't, try using `text()` instead.

Comment: I try xpath and css locator as well but it yield the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try these XPaths:

```
"//table/tr[2]/td/a"
```

or

```
"//a[contains(text(), 'What Ever Company')]"
```

Should work.